# diagraming plugin for wiki in vsts online

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

vsts online introduces wiki feature in its latest additions.

Are there any diagramming tool available as a plugin for creating wiki in the newly introduced wiki tool in vsts online?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [wiki extension overview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=agile-extensions.wiki#overview), it will be available.

> Built with extensibility in mind
>
> Want to see diagrams, mind maps and more in your wikis?
>
> With the extensibility model we enable integrations with existing
>   tools to really make your wiki pages come alive.

On the other hand, you can clone it to local and modify, then push to server.

[Add and edit pages in your team project wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/add-edit-wiki)

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question but there are updates. Azure DevOps Wiki (Services & Server) now supports **limited** [Mermaid diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#add-mermaid-diagrams-to-a-wiki-page); just Sequence diagrams, Gantt charts, and Flowcharts.

Sadly Azure DevOps Wiki is stuck at an older [Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/) version, making it troublesome to use as the newer, documented [Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/) syntax often does not work.

Comment: **Additional updates.** Per the [Add Mermaid diagrams to a wiki page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#add-mermaid-diagrams-to-a-wiki-page) supported diagrams now include: Sequence diagrams, Gantt charts, Flowcharts, Class diagram, State diagram, User journey, Pie chart, and Requirements diagram.